# Django templates and DRY - how to avoid duplicated HTML

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have recently started to use Django templates and I've often found the following pattern in others' code:

```
  {% ifequal value 1 %}
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.name }}" id="{{ item.name }}" checked="checked" />
  {% else %}
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.name }}" id="{{ item.name }}"  />
```

Conditions with Django template variables are being used to define the value of one or more HTML element attributes. This duplicates HTML code and breaks DRY principle. How could I avoid that?

Alternatives I have considered:

1) embed the condition in the checked attribute.

- Pro: DRY-compliant
- Con: makes code harder to read, specially if condition is more complex and several HTML element attributes are manipulated

2) Define Javascript variables using the template variable values and generate HTML elements with Javascript.

- Pro: DRY-compliant
- Con: move logic to client-side

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The real way to deal with this is to use Django's forms framework, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with that snippet. It might break some DRY but the code is ultimately very readable and maintainable.

Two core philosophies from the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) are

> Explicit is better than implicit

and

> Readability counts

Generating HTML via JavaScript is definitely not explicit, while putting conditions inside a element affect readability.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can simplify things quite a bit (see below):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.name }}" id="{{ item.name }}" {% ifequal value 1 %}checked="checked"{% endif %} />
```

As you can see, there's no need to duplicate the code here -- you can embed your if statement inside the HTML to save text.

Comment: That's alternative 1 I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

As a third option you can use your view to control the `checked="checked"` part.

Make a pseudo field called e.g. `"checked"` that is attached to each of your items and will hold either an empty string (not `None`) or `checked="checked"` based on the fact if value is 1 or not, or whatever your condition will be.

You will allow you to write:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.name }}" id="{{ item.name }}" {{ item.checked }}  />
```

This applies to the DRY principe and it is still explicit. Although this will be shifted to your view.

Comment: But then UI details are handled by backend, this is not good imho.

Comment: I willing to agree Alan, because I see where you are coming from. However I would like to quote the Django Documentation: " The view itself contains whatever arbitrary logic is necessary to return that response." So it basically says, you can put this logic in your view OR your template. So you mist decide what suits or overall design more. I'm not saying the in-template handling is wrong. It just... depends...